# Padding MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to retrieve logs of our plant where a certain event has occurred.

At the moment, I can query the actual event by using an alarm_code field. However, I'd also like to include about an hour's worth of data before and after the alarm event.

How would I go about doing this?

The timestamp field is also the primary key, if that helps.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (My_Field_List) 
FROM My_Table 
WHERE My_Timestamp BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, -1, Alarm_Time) 
  AND TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 1, Alarm_Time);
```

Details available in the ever useful documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd).

**Example:**

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Sample(My_Timestamp TIMESTAMP);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.71 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM Sample;
+---------------------+
| My_Timestamp        |
+---------------------+
| 1999-01-01 00:00:01 |
| 2010-01-01 00:00:01 |
+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT My_Timestamp FROM Sample WHERE My_Timestamp BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, -1, '1999-01-01 00:00:01') AND TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 1, '1999-01-01 00:00:01');
+---------------------+
| My_Timestamp        |
+---------------------+
| 1999-01-01 00:00:01 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I can see how to do this, but I have one more question. The current datalog has a DATETIME field that records all the time, whereas Alarm_Time would be a subset of the DATETIME. How would I define the Alarm_Time?

Comment: I'm not quite with you. Your Alarm_Time is a moment in time - your original post mentioned TIMESTAMP, but now you're saying it's DATETIME? Could you give a SHOW CREATE TABLE My_Table? Edit your original question. In any case, the same code should work with a DATETIME.

Comment: Sorry for the delay! 

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

SELECT DATETIME, ALARM_CODE, PRESSURE FROM `plant_table` WHERE (ALARM_CODE > 700 AND ALARM_CODE < 800) OR _DATETIME ±1 HOUR_;

Thanks again!

Comment: Does something like this work? It should.
SELECT My_DATETIME, ALARM_CODE, PRESSURE 
FROM plant_table 
WHERE (ALARM_CODE > 700 AND ALARM_CODE < 800) 
OR My_DATETIME ±1 BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, -1, '1999-01-01 00:00:01') 
AND TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 1, '1999-01-01 00:00:01'); You obviously have to manually specify your My_Datetime for the value of your alarm time. I chose '1999-01-01 00:00:01' just as an example.